# Can't disable screen blanking

Tags: raspbian

I'm using a raspberry pi for a project. It's equipped with a 7 inch LCD touch display. I'm running a QT-application without a display manager.

I've edited /etc/rc.local with the following line: "su -c startx pi&" and the /home/pi/.xinitrc contains "/home/pi/bin/0027". This all works, the pi starts up and the application 0027 is loading without a display manager.

The problem is that the LCD blanks after 10 minutes, regardless of the things I've tried.

I've tried the following:

In the file /etc/kbd/config I've changed to the following:
BLANK_TIME=0
POWERDOWN_TIME=0
BLANK_DPMS=off

In the file /boot/cmdline.txt I've added "consoleblank=0"

In the file /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart, I've added:
@xset s noblank
@xset s off
@xset -dpms

In the file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf after [SeatDefault] I added "xserver-command=X -s 0 dpms"

Nothing helps, the screen blanks after 10 minutes no matter what! I've read that 10 minutes is the kernel default, so I seems that all other settings are ignored. Is this due to the fact that I doesn't use a display manager?

Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

There was no problem with Raspbian, the problem was the QT-app.

By mistake I compiled it as debug, and that caused this problem. I recompiled it as release and the problem is gone!